# BRMS 6 ACL - Not Restricting Custom Roles

Tags: acl, drools, user-permissions, workbench, drools-guvnor

I want to put access control on the BRMS repository/project access, so that developer-A can only work on repository-A. We have a central BRMS which has one repository per project. We have 20 projects and have 20 repository, one for each project.

We strongly want that user working on project-A do not have access on project-B in BRMS.

I read the documentation that says,

**"The user either has to belong into a role that has access to the repository or to a role that belongs into an orgazinational group that has access to the repository. These restrictions can be managed with the command line config tool."**

Our implementation to the above doc statement is to create custom roles. To do this we simply ran KIE-CONFIG-CLI commands like "add-role-repo" and considered that roles got added to the BRMS. BUT WE ARE UNABLE to associate the permission (read/write, developer/admin) to our custom roles.

and upon login we are getting error "Login Faile : UNAuthorized"

**QUESTION** How can we have the ACL implemented. Is there something which we are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACL in BPMS is only role based.